# End of Project process

Tags: project

After having completed a few projects I am searching for an alternative approach to the final process. I develop and design websites, and at the end of each project, I have a meeting with my clients to show them how to use their websites and give them a PDF instruction manual.

Creating the manual eats up some of my time and I am looking to minimize this as much as possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you modularizing your projects?

Comment: Are you factoring in the time taken to prepare and present the final PDF into your quote? Or, if hourly, charging them for the time? If either of these are true, then why remove it from the process? THis is the kind of thing which gives the client a warm-and-fuzzy feeling and brings them back for more.

Comment: You give a good point. The warm/fuzzy aspect important and the pdf is more or less included. I was just looking for a better process.

Comment: Maybe think about a screen capture recorder, together with audio, for visual tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a video alternative?

If the PDF manual is that important so that the client can use their website in ways they wouldn't be able to without it - then I would suggest creating a video showcasing all of the topics that would be in the PDF.

The video could cut down the time it would require you to write out a PDF and will give better visuals than flat images on a PDF.

All you would need to do is use a screen recording software which can also record your voice - or you can do a voice over.

Comment: I haven't delved into video tutorials yet

Answer (score 1):

Include the time for creating the manual in your cost, so you're getting paid to do it. Work on the manual as you develop so that it isn't a big chore to go back and do the whole thing from scratch after the development is done.